# Single line ellipsis in Material-UI Select and option Component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a TableHead Component with multiple columns. One of them is a `<Select>` so that you can filter the content of the table (the value is one of 4 statuses in my case). I want to add an ellipsis at the end of the options' string if it's longer than it's container.

My problem is that material-ui's styles are wrapped around the Select component so whether I do it withStyles or by inserting styles inside the tag, it doesn't work.

I checked and with material-UI you can have `noWrap` and `textOverflow: "ellipsis"` should work but I can't quite figure out the right combination.

My expected result is that if the string is larger than it's parent, it displays the Ellipsis. So instead of this:

[image: 1]]

I'd like a simple "Contrib..." (The svg from Material-UI Select component overlays the text...)

I tried many different options but none of them do anything so clearly I must be doing something wrong. I tried changing colors to see if my styles were being affected which they are.

```
<Grid item sm={2} lg={2} style={{display: 'flex', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Select native style={{ textOverflow: "ellipsis", overflow: "hidden", whiteSpace: "pre" }}
            value={this.state.status}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, Filter.Status)}>
        {Object.keys(StatusFilter).filter(key => !isNaN(Number(StatusFilter[key]))).map(item => {
            return (<option key={item} value={StatusFilter[item]}>{this.getStatus(StatusFilter[item])}</option>);
        })}
    </Select>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things here, first a native select has no way to add ellipsis since text-overflow is only for block elements. See [Is it possible to make text-overflow:ellipsis for select with css only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494203/is-it-possible-to-make-text-overflowellipsis-for-select-with-css-only)

In case you want to explore that way, there is also `inputProps` that is an object you can use to pass properties to the underlying input. So if you want to add a style to the native input you can:

```
   <Select native inputProps={{ style: { width: 100 } }}>{...}</Select>
```

On the other hand, if you remove the `native` property the ellipsis should be applied by default if the select box is smaller than the text.

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do was remove the `native` parameter from the `<Select>` component, replace `<option>` with `<MenuItem>` and set the maximum width to the right parent: `maxWidth: '100%'`

Answer (score 2):

In my case ellipses were missing even on non native Select component, and that was because `display: flex` style was applied over 'MuiSelect-root' component.

Replace that - i.e. with `display:block` - and ellipsis will be there for you.

Comment: had a problem with all select options showing on the same line and when changing it as mentioned above, it displays it correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
            <FormControl
              variant="outlined"
              margin="dense"
              className={classes.formControl}
              error={touched.test && Boolean(errors.test)}
              >
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Test</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                value={course}
                name="test"
                onChange={handleChange}
                label="Test"
              >
                <MenuItem value="">
                  <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={4}>4</MenuItem>
              </Select>
              <FormHelperText error={touched.test && Boolean(errors.test)}>{errors.test}</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
```

And add class:
formControl: {
width: "100%",
},