# Select dropdown Option content wrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Select `dropdown` wrap not working and I used:

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

but no result.Any one can help on this

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
<select  style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="">Volvo</option>
  <option value="">You already have a live sesstion of this application open.Yoy can only have one session of this application in this webpage at a time.</option>
  <option value="">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shree Khanal did you edit this snippet?, I did'nt got any update

Comment: It's not possible in the simple select tag but you can get your requirement by using any custom plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make text-overflow:ellipsis for select with css only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494203/is-it-possible-to-make-text-overflowellipsis-for-select-with-css-only)

Comment: Use javascript solution or custom dropdown. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676701/set-width-at-option-of-select-box)

Comment: i think you you have to use some plugin to achieve this. like https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

Answer (score 0):

You can't format line breaks into an option; however, you can use the title attribute to give a mouse-over tooltip to give the full info. Use a short descriptor in the option text and give the full skinny in the title.

```
<option value="1" title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!">1</option>
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
<select  style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="">Volvo</option>
  <option value="">You already have a live sesstion of this application open.Yoy can only have one session of this application in this webpage at a time.</option>
  <option value="">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="">Audi</option>
  <option value="1" title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!">1</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Usually options cannot be style. So you can use jquery like this

```js
$('option').each(function(){
   var text=$(this).text()
   $(this).val(text).text(text.substr(0,50)+'…')
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 200px;">
<select  style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="">Volvo</option>
  <option value="">You already have a live sesstion of this application open.Yoy can only have one session of this application in this webpage at a time.</option>
  <option value="">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have given `text.substr(0,50)` you can Change.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my client is not accepting for this solution, He wants wrap the text into second line any alternate solution please